# mtrpacket: error - mtrpacket.ProcessError: failure to communicate with subprocess "mtr-packet"

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-asyncio

While we are trying to run and get the traceroute output using mtrpacket getting below error

```
import asyncio
import mtrpacket

#  A simple coroutine which will start an mtrpacket session and
#  ping localhost
async def probe():
    async with mtrpacket.MtrPacket() as mtr:
        return await mtr.probe('10.11.12.13')

#  Use asyncio's event loop to start the coroutine and wait for the probe
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    result = loop.run_until_complete(probe())
finally:
    loop.close()

#  Print the probe result
print(result)


Error: mtrpacket.ProcessError: failure to communicate with subprocess "mtr-packet"  (is it installed and in the PATH?)
mtr-packet: Failure to open IPv4 sockets: Permission denied
mtr-packet: Failure to open IPv6 sockets: Permission denied
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: please update the question to provide more information into the environment that this is trying to be run on?

Answer (score 1):

`mtr-packet` is designed to run with raw socket access.  If you are using Linux, you can use capabilities to grant the binary socket access.  On other Unix-like operating systems, including MacOS, it should be suid root.

The following commands will grant it access to raw sockets.

For Linux:

```
sudo chown root $(which mtr-packet)
sudo setcap cap_net_raw+ep $(which mtr-packet)
```

For other operating systems:

```
sudo chown root $(which mtr-packet)
sudo chmod u+s $(which mtr-packet)
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably socket permissions, try running with sudo access and that might do the trick.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer